# How to express a vector as scalar combinations of a separate orthonormal set?

Tags: linear-algebra

In an orthonormal set with $
q_1=
 \left[\begin{matrix}
\frac 13 \\
\frac 23 \\
\frac {-2}3  \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$
$
q_2=
 \left[\begin{matrix}
0 \\
\frac {1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$
and $
q_3=
 \left[\begin{matrix}
\frac {-4}{\sqrt{18}} \\
\frac {1}{\sqrt{18}} \\
\frac {-1}{\sqrt{18}}  \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$

Express the vector $
w=
 \left[\begin{matrix}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$
in terms of q1, q2, and q3. That is, find c1, c2,and c3 such that:

$
w=
 \left[\begin{matrix}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
= c_1q_1 + c_2q_2 + c_3q_3
$

I don't understand the c variables' function in this question. I assume they represent scalars, but I can't say for certain. Also, assuming that they do represent scalars, does a systematic approach exist for finding a solution, or do I have to rely on guessing and checking?

I feel like I might have missed a fundamental relationship that exists in the problem.

Comment: Did you mean 18 rather than 16 for q3?

Comment: Oops yes I did, thanks

Answer (score 1):

They are scalars. Here is how to formulate this problem

$$ w=
 \left[\begin{matrix}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
= c_1 \left[\begin{matrix}
\frac 13 \\
\frac 23 \\
\frac {-2}3  \\
\end{matrix}\right] + c_2 \left[\begin{matrix}
0 \\
\frac {1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
\end{matrix}\right] + c_3 \left[\begin{matrix}
\frac {-4}{\sqrt{18}} \\
\frac {1}{\sqrt{18}} \\
\frac {-1}{\sqrt{18}}  \\
\end{matrix}\right] = 
\left[ \matrix{ \frac{1}{3} & 0 & -\frac{4}{\sqrt{18}} \\ \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{18}} \\ -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}} } \right] 
\left[\matrix{c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3}\right]$$

You can solve the above with matrix inversion (which in case it is equal to the transpose since the matrix is orthonormal).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the matrix visualization

Answer (score 0):

if the set of vectors really is orthonormal, the coefficient $c_i = w \cdot q_i$ the dot product

Comment: That’s so intuitive, thank you for dragging me out of the haze of problem set fatigue haha.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are orthonormal, so $$\underline{q_i}\cdot\underline{q_j}=0 \ \ \ for \ i \neq j \ and \\ \underline{q_i}\cdot\underline{q_i}=1$$

Consider
$$
\underline{w}
= c_1 \underline{q_1} + c_2\underline{q_2} + c_3\underline{q_3}
\\ \implies \underline{w}\cdot\underline{q_1}= c_1 \underline{q_1}\cdot\underline{q_1} + c_2\underline{q_2}\cdot\underline{q_1} + c_3\underline{q_3}\cdot\underline{q_1}
$$

$$\implies \underline{w}\cdot\underline{q_1}= c_1 \underline{q_1}\cdot\underline{q_1}+0+0$$
so $c_1=\frac{\underline{w}\cdot\underline{q_1}}{\underline{q_1}\cdot\underline{q_1}}=\underline{w}\cdot\underline{q_1}$

You can repeat these steps by dotting other vectors from the orthonormal set to find out $c_2 ,c_3$

Comment: Thank you for the concrete example!